# Cannot style header row for custom field components inside Datagrid

Tags: react-admin

When using a custom field as a child of Datagrid, there appears to be no way to style the column header.
Specifically, I would like to add a left margin to the column header text.
The docs say to use `headerClassName`, but this has no effect when used with a custom component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { List, Datagrid, TextField } from 'react-admin';

const TextField = ({ source, record = {} }) => <span>{record[source]}</span>;

export const UserList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="lastName" label="Last Name" />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

In the code sample, how can I add style to the `Last Name` column header?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS API: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-datagrid-component

> Tip: If you want to override the header and cell styles independently for each column, use the headerClassName and cellClassName props in  components. For instance, to hide a certain column on small screens:

Example from documentation:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = theme => ({
    hiddenOnSmallScreens: {
        [theme.breakpoints.down('md')]: {
            display: 'none',
        },
    },
});

const PostList = ({ classes, ...props }) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="title" />
            <TextField
                source="views"
                headerClassName={classes.hiddenOnSmallScreens}
                cellClassName={classes.hiddenOnSmallScreens}
            />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(PostList);
```